# Xcode UIView has no members like border color and etc

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, xcode, uiview

Screenshot: [image]
if I use it in code then receive this message: 
[image]
like: Value of type 'UIView' has no member cornerRadius
What is wrong? Yesterday I didn't have this problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use Button's layer to set border property. e.g:

```
button.layer.cornerRadius = button.frame.height / 2.0
button.layer.masksToBounds = true
button.layer.borderColor = UIColor.lightGray.cgColor
button.layer.borderWidth = 1.0
```

**OR**

Add this extension to get these options in storyboard.

```
    extension UIView {
    @IBInspectable var cornerRadius: CGFloat {
        get {
            return layer.cornerRadius
        }
        set {
            layer.cornerRadius = newValue
            layer.masksToBounds = newValue > 0
        }
    }
    @IBInspectable var borderWidth: CGFloat {
        get {
            return layer.borderWidth
        }
        set {
            layer.borderWidth = newValue
        }
    }
    @IBInspectable var borderColor: UIColor? {
        get {
            let color = UIColor.init(cgColor: layer.borderColor!)
            return color
        }
        set {
            layer.borderColor = newValue?.cgColor
        }
    }
    @IBInspectable var shadowRadius: CGFloat {
        get {
            return layer.shadowRadius
        }
        set {
            layer.shadowColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
            layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 0, height: 2)
            layer.shadowOpacity = 0.4
            layer.shadowRadius = shadowRadius
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, right, there was a mistake. But why I don't have this options in Storyboard ?

Comment: By default these options are not editable in storyboard. If you want you can add a `UIView extension` to get these options in storyboard. Check updated answer.

Comment: Thanks!!! I used library "Material" and It has this one by default, yesterday I removed this library and it happened) I thought this are default settings in ios ( I'm new in ios programming )

Answer (score 0):

It should be like this

```
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>

[[myButton layer] setBorderWidth:2.0f];

[[myButton layer] setBorderColor:[UIColor greenColor].CGColor];

myButton.layer.cornerRadius = myButton.frame.height / 2.0;
```

For ref:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/32468101/5184217

Answer (score 0):

You cannot set CALayer properties directly to UIElement. Instead, need to use **.layer** property.

Example:

```
button.layer.cornerRadius = button.frame.height/ 2.0

button.layer.maskToBounds = true
```